# Firefox Apparmor Profile

Tags: security, apparmor

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 19.04.  I want to enable apparmor for Firefox.  I found an existing profile in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox, which I enabled by deleting /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.bin.firefox.

It is mostly working, but I've noticed one issue.  I can't open my downloads from Firefox.  I can't even "Open Containing Folder" on a download.  Both ask me what application I want to use to perform the action.

Here are the errors I see from Firefox when I run it.  Those first 4 apparmor errors happen as soon as I launch Firefox.  The last 3 "cannot launch" errors happen when I try and open downloads.

```
** (firefox:6062): WARNING **: 17:58:37.874: Unable to query dbus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.138" (uid=1000 pid=6062 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox " label="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

** (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:6127): WARNING **: 17:58:38.319: Unable to query dbus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.140" (uid=1000 pid=6127 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -" label="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

** (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:6184): WARNING **: 17:58:38.954: Unable to query dbus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.141" (uid=1000 pid=6184 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -" label="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

** (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:6253): WARNING **: 17:58:40.358: Unable to query dbus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.142" (uid=1000 pid=6253 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -" label="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

** (firefox:6062): WARNING **: 17:58:51.217: Cannot launch default application: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop” (Permission denied)

** (firefox:6062): WARNING **: 17:58:51.227: Cannot launch default application: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop” (Permission denied)

** (firefox:6062): WARNING **: 17:58:54.538: Cannot launch default application: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop” (Permission denied)
```

Here is my full policy:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Author: Jamie Strandboge <jamie@canonical.com>

# Declare an apparmor variable to help with overrides
@{MOZ_LIBDIR}=/usr/lib/firefox

#include <tunables/global>

# We want to confine the binaries that match:
#  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
#  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
# but not:
#  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} {
  #include <abstractions/audio>
  #include <abstractions/cups-client>
  #include <abstractions/dbus-strict>
  #include <abstractions/dbus-session-strict>
  #include <abstractions/dconf>
  #include <abstractions/gnome>
  #include <abstractions/ibus>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/openssl>
  #include <abstractions/p11-kit>
  #include <abstractions/ubuntu-unity7-base>
  #include <abstractions/ubuntu-unity7-launcher>

  #include <abstractions/dbus-accessibility-strict>
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       peer=(name=org.a11y.Bus),
  dbus (receive)
       bus=session
       interface=org.a11y.atspi**,
  dbus (receive, send)
       bus=accessibility,

  # for networking
  network inet stream,
  network inet6 stream,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/arp r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/if_inet6 r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/ipv6_route r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/dev r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/wireless r,
  dbus (send)
       bus=system
       path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager
       member=state,
  dbus (receive)
       bus=system
       path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager,

  # should maybe be in abstractions
  /etc/ r,
  /etc/mime.types r,
  /etc/mailcap r,
  /etc/xdg/*buntu/applications/defaults.list    r, # for all derivatives
  /etc/xfce4/defaults.list r,
  /usr/share/xubuntu/applications/defaults.list r,
  owner @{HOME}/.local/share/applications/defaults.list r,
  owner @{HOME}/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list r,
  owner @{HOME}/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache r,
  /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache r,
  /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/*.desktop r,
  owner /tmp/** m,
  owner /var/tmp/** m,
  owner /{,var/}run/shm/shmfd-* rw,
  owner /{dev,run}/shm/org.{chromium,mozilla}.* rwk,
  /tmp/.X[0-9]*-lock r,
  /etc/udev/udev.conf r,
  # Doesn't seem to be required, but noisy. Maybe allow 'r' for 'b*' if needed.
  # Possibly move to an abstraction if anything else needs it.
  deny /run/udev/data/** r,
  # let the shell know we launched something
  dbus (send)
     bus=session
     interface=org.gtk.gio.DesktopAppInfo
     member=Launched,

  /etc/timezone r,
  /etc/wildmidi/wildmidi.cfg r,

  # firefox specific
  /etc/firefox*/ r,
  /etc/firefox*/** r,
  /etc/xul-ext/** r,
  /etc/xulrunner-2.0*/ r,
  /etc/xulrunner-2.0*/** r,
  /etc/gre.d/ r,
  /etc/gre.d/* r,

  # noisy
  deny @{MOZ_LIBDIR}/** w,
  deny /usr/lib/firefox-addons/** w,
  deny /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/** w,
  deny /usr/lib/xulrunner-*/components/*.tmp w,
  deny /.suspended r,
  deny /boot/initrd.img* r,
  deny /boot/vmlinuz* r,
  deny /var/cache/fontconfig/ w,
  deny @{HOME}/.local/share/recently-used.xbel r,

  # TODO: investigate
  deny /usr/bin/gconftool-2 x,

  # These are needed when a new user starts firefox and firefox.sh is used
  @{MOZ_LIBDIR}/** ixr,
  /usr/bin/basename ixr,
  /usr/bin/dirname ixr,
  /usr/bin/pwd ixr,
  /sbin/killall5 ixr,
  /bin/which ixr,
  /usr/bin/tr ixr,
  @{PROC}/ r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/cmdline r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/mountinfo r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/stat r,
  owner @{PROC}/[0-9]*/task/[0-9]*/stat r,
  @{PROC}/[0-9]*/status r,
  @{PROC}/filesystems r,
  @{PROC}/sys/vm/overcommit_memory r,
  /sys/devices/pci[0-9]*/**/uevent r,
  /sys/devices/platform/**/uevent r,
  /sys/devices/pci*/**/{busnum,idVendor,idProduct} r,
  /sys/devices/pci*/**/{,subsystem_}device r,
  /sys/devices/pci*/**/{,subsystem_}vendor r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/node[0-9]*/meminfo r,
  owner @{HOME}/.cache/thumbnails/** rw,

  /etc/mtab r,
  /etc/fstab r,

  # Needed for the crash reporter
  owner @{PROC}/[0-9]*/environ r,
  owner @{PROC}/[0-9]*/auxv r,
  /etc/lsb-release r,
  /usr/bin/expr ix,
  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/cpu/** r,

  # about:memory
  owner @{PROC}/[0-9]*/statm r,
  owner @{PROC}/[0-9]*/smaps r,

  # Needed for container to work in xul builds
  /usr/lib/xulrunner-*/plugin-container ixr,

  # allow access to documentation and other files the user may want to look
  # at in /usr and /opt
  /usr/ r,
  /usr/** r,
  /opt/ r,
  /opt/** r,

  # so browsing directories works
  / r,
  /**/ r,

  # Default profile allows downloads to ~/Downloads and uploads from ~/Public
  owner @{HOME}/ r,
  owner @{HOME}/Public/ r,
  owner @{HOME}/Public/* r,
  owner @{HOME}/Downloads/ r,
  owner @{HOME}/Downloads/* rw,

  # per-user firefox configuration
  owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/ rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/** rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/**/*.{db,parentlock,sqlite}* k,
  owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/plugins/** rm,
  owner @{HOME}/.{firefox,mozilla}/**/plugins/** rm,
  owner @{HOME}/.gnome2/firefox* rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.cache/mozilla/{,firefox/} rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.cache/mozilla/firefox/** rw,
  owner @{HOME}/.cache/mozilla/firefox/**/*.sqlite k,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks r,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/dconf/user w,
  owner /{,var/}run/user/*/dconf/user w,
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/org/gnome/GConf/Server
       member=GetDefaultDatabase
       peer=(label=unconfined),
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/org/gnome/GConf/Database/*
       member={AddMatch,AddNotify,AllEntries,LookupExtended,RemoveNotify}
       peer=(label=unconfined),
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/org/gtk/vfs/mounttracker
       interface=org.gtk.vfs.MountTracker
       member=ListMountableInfo
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  # gnome-session
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/org/gnome/SessionManager
       interface=org.gnome.SessionManager
       member={Inhibit,Uninhibit}
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  # unity screen API
  dbus (send)
       bus=system
       interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
       path="/com/canonical/Unity/Screen"
       member="Introspect"
       peer=(label=unconfined),
  dbus (send)
       bus=system
       interface="com.canonical.Unity.Screen"
       path="/com/canonical/Unity/Screen"
       member={keepDisplayOn,removeDisplayOnRequest}
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  # freedesktop.org ScreenSaver
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/{,org/freedesktop/,org.gnome/}Screen{s,S}aver
       interface=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
       member={Inhibit,UnInhibit,SimulateUserActivity}
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  # gnome, kde and cinnamon screensaver
  dbus (send)
       bus=session
       path=/{,ScreenSaver}
       interface=org.{gnome.ScreenSaver,kde.screensaver,cinnamon.ScreenSaver}
       member=SimulateUserActivity
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  # UPower
  dbus (send)
       bus=system
       path=/org/freedesktop/UPower
       interface=org.freedesktop.UPower
       member=EnumerateDevices
       peer=(label=unconfined),

  #
  # Extensions
  # /usr/share/.../extensions/... is already covered by '/usr/** r', above.
  # Allow 'x' for downloaded extensions, but inherit policy for safety
  owner @{HOME}/.mozilla/**/extensions/** mixr,

  deny @{MOZ_LIBDIR}/update.test w,
  deny /usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/**/ w,
  deny /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/extensions/**/ w,
  deny /usr/share/mozilla/extensions/**/ w,
  deny /usr/share/mozilla/ w,

  # Miscellaneous (to be abstracted)
  # Ideally these would use a child profile. They are all ELF executables
  # so running with 'Ux', while not ideal, is ok because we will at least
  # benefit from glibc's secure execute.
  /usr/bin/mkfifo Uxr,  # investigate
  /bin/ps Uxr,
  /bin/uname Uxr,

  /usr/bin/lsb_release Cxr -> lsb_release,
  profile lsb_release {
    #include <abstractions/base>
    #include <abstractions/python>
    /usr/bin/lsb_release r,
    /bin/dash ixr,
    /usr/bin/dpkg-query ixr,
    /usr/include/python2.[4567]/pyconfig.h r,
    /etc/lsb-release r,
    /etc/debian_version r,
    /usr/share/distro-info/*.csv r,
    /var/lib/dpkg/** r,

    /usr/local/lib/python3.[0-6]/dist-packages/ r,
    /usr/bin/ r,
    /usr/bin/python3.[0-6] mr,

    # file_inherit
    deny /tmp/gtalkplugin.log w,
  }

  # Addons
  #include <abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/firefox>

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.bin.firefox>
}
```

I tried to allow those ListNames methods myself, but I really have no idea what I am doing.  I also tried to run firefox with aa-genprof, but I never saw these violations pop up while I did that.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1. I'd like to know more about this to.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I answered the question assuming you had no downloads directory specification in your profile entries. I now see you have.

```
owner @{HOME}/Downloads/ r,
owner @{HOME}/Downloads/* rw,
```

I do notice you have no downloads given in abstractions. Try checking in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions for a user-downloads file, and including it instead of the download location entries. Try reglobbing the entry to a coarser allow (editing or trying to create profiles benefits from a coarse start before specifying exact subdirs, libs, etc.).

I have encountered some oddities of this kind running Apparmor too. Unloaded profiles affecting an application, even when teardown and restart are used to reload profiles now set to complain, continue to affect the app (apt-get, for example). Some applications are also proving hard to profile despite allowing extremely coarse-grained access to any libs, etc., required, which will still show as denies in complain logs.

Your example is not encouraging.

I can't speak for the console denies, though I am used to seeing some Gtk errors as standard which I understand shouldn't really be there (bad window messages); and since I block writing to dconf files as a matter of course, these are always printed as complains if I bother to run from the term.

I would also advise checking the allows in the profile against a working firejail profile if you can. Firejail is considerably more simplified and coarse-grained than Apparmor, but my working firefox-portable profile includes no dbus allowance, so I am surprised to see it specified for the (admittedly different) installed app.

My current problem is the apparent impossiblity of getting Firefox to run with extensions under an apparmor profile, and no amount of lsof, strace or profile allows solves the problem.

I'm on the verge of giving up on apparmor and just making do with SELinux instead, which is a simpler profile model. There are few real working profiles for apparmor, which isn't even bundled with operational profiles in Debian, and I also use a portable version of Firefox anyway. Apparmor is incredibly granular and requires copious application-system knowledge.